# how to feed the async output to express renderer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, pug

I make a request to get a sample XML file, parse it and now I would like to pass it to Express renderer to dynamically display the value on a page. My renderer router:

```
app.get('/dynamic_view', function(req, res){
    res.render('dynamic', {
        name: //pass my output here
    });
 });
```

and I get my async output like this:

```
const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
const axios = require('axios');

let url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml';

    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        parseString(response.data, function (err, result) {
          console.log(result.breakfast_menu.food[0].name); // returns 'Belgian Waffles'
        });        
      })
```

How do I pass my Async variable output, which should be 'Belgian Waffles', to `name` property of `res.renderer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
const axios = require('axios');

let url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml';

app.get('/dynamic_view', function(req, res, next){
    axios.get(url)
      .then(response => {
        parseString(response.data, function (err, result) {
          if (err) return next(err)
          res.render('dynamic', {
            name: result.breakfast_menu.food[0].name
          });
        });        
      })
 });
```